# Calendar image representing column value in Tibco spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I am trying to build a spotfire dashboard in which i want to display a calendar image with some date has to be shown, the date value to be shown has to be picked from column in my table. Can someone help how to add this?

My desired image would look like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom HTML to a TextArea - Import your image and use calculated values as the text in the TextArea. The set up would require some CSS and possible js as you'd wanted to have your calculated values placement be over your image.

Comment: This. Also, if you need specific HTML or JS help please add the code you have tried and tag your question with those Web Development tags.

Comment: Since i am not good at JS/HTML.I haven't tried any HTML or JS.